# GridBagLayout taking up taking over half the panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Ok so I'm having some trouble with `GridBagLayouts` and getting them to size the way I want them to. In this case I want the container pane split into 2 halves, but I can't seem to do that. I've tried several variations of the `weightx` and `weighty` values which I presume is the problem because they are the values I understand the least. The pane is split into 2 halves (only equal in width, but different sized heights. I believe I know how to do this so I just need to fix the horizontal problem), but only when I don't have my `JTextArea` added on the left side. When I do add it, it pushed the right side to the very right of the pane and gives that side only the bare minimum of space it needs. Below is the relevant code that contains the code for the `GridBagLayout` and 2 pictures showing what I mean. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Code**

`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Sample extends JFrame
{
    public Sample()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        GridBagConstraints cGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        cGBC.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cGBC.gridx = 0;
        cGBC.gridy = 0;
        cGBC.weightx = .5;
        cGBC.weighty = 1;
        cGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        cGBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        Font titleFont = new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 16);

        JPanel leftSide = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        leftSide.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JLabel leftTitle = new JLabel("Objective");
        leftTitle.setFont(titleFont);
        leftTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

        GridBagConstraints leftGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        leftGBC.gridx =0;
        leftGBC.gridy = 0;
        leftGBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        leftGBC.weightx = 1;
        leftGBC.weighty = .1;
        leftGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

        leftSide.add(leftTitle, leftGBC);
        leftGBC.gridy = 1;
        leftGBC.weightx = 0;

        //If you comment this section out, it will become 50/50 again
        JTextArea objectiveArea = new JTextArea("TestTTestTest TestTest TestTest TestTest TestTest TestTest "
                + "TestTest TestTest TestTest TestTest TestTest TestTest "
                + "TestTest TestTest TestTest TestTest TestTest ");
        objectiveArea.setEditable(false);
        objectiveArea.setFocusable(false);
        objectiveArea.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        objectiveArea.setLineWrap(true);
        objectiveArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        leftSide.add(objectiveArea, leftGBC);

        add(leftSide, cGBC);
        cGBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        cGBC.weightx = .5;
        cGBC.gridx = 1;

        JPanel rightSide = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        rightSide.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JLabel rightTitle = new JLabel("Controls");
        rightTitle.setFont(titleFont);
        rightTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

        GridBagConstraints rightGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        rightGBC.gridx = 0;
        rightGBC.gridy = 0;
        rightGBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        rightGBC.weightx = 1;
        rightGBC.weighty = 1;
        rightGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

        rightSide.add(rightTitle, rightGBC);

        rightGBC.gridx = 0;
        rightGBC.gridy = 1;
        rightGBC.weightx = 0.5;
        rightGBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        rightGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

        JPanel controlPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2, 2, 2));
        controlPane.add(new JLabel("test1"));
        controlPane.add(new JLabel("test2"));
        controlPane.add(new JLabel("test3"));
        controlPane.add(new JLabel("test4"));

        rightSide.add(controlPane, rightGBC);

        add(rightSide, cGBC);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Sample();
    }
}
```

`

**Visual**
[image]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. 3) Please learn how to crop images..

Comment: *"split into 2 halves"* Two ***equal*** halves? Use a single row `GridLayout`. Having said that.. `leftGBC.weightx = 1;` should be `.5` for both sides.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm aware that I should provide an actual sample of the code, I didn't in this case because I struggle with `GridBagLayouts` and hoped the code provided was enough. And I only want the 2 halves equal in width, not height(I'll edit my post to make this more clear). The sample picture doesn't show what I want in the end, but if I can solve the equal width problem, I believe I know how to get to that end. I had considered using a  `GridLayout` but I don't want the right side to fill out vertically.

Comment: *"I don't want the right side to fill out vertically."* So there is just a gap beneath, or above, or divided evenly between.. Oh never mind, not enough time to play '20 questions'. Since you could not be bothered taking my advice, I'll just vote to close.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The code is now replaced with a fully runnable .java file. The sample picture is still there but unchanged because it is unnecessary now that there is a working sample. And as for your question, there will be a gap at the bottom by setting `rightGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH`. But I'm not entirely sure how this is relevant with the horizontal spacing. And I will apologize in advance for possible erratic variable values because I was trying everything and anything I could to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Some general tips: 1) Gice code samples more unique names than `Sample`. For this case, something like `SampleGBLWithTwoHalves` would be more decriptive and less likely to be the same as the other code in my 'test code' package. 2) When debugging layouts, apply borders to help distinguish between the panels. I typically use a colored border - different color for each panel. 3) When making an MCVE, remove irrelevant cruft like setting a text area focusable or editable. 4) *"The sample picture is still there but unchanged because it is unnecessary now that there is a working sample."* ..

Comment: .. 4) (cont.) Post ASSCI art / drawing as I recommended several comments ago! The current image does not tell us how extra space is supposed to be assigned! 5) Typically it's better to create a panel and set it as the content pane, than try to deal with the existing content pane.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I didn't come here to post the perfect SO question. I just need some help understanding why it isn't filling out the way I want it too. I still don't see how the extra vertical space is relevant. I added a sample .java class to make it easier because I know it is bad practice to not do so. And rather than helping me, you've made several posts critiquing my SO question, even though compared to other problems I would think it would be a quick fix and wouldn't require the perfect SO question format. And since I don't appear to be getting any help I will take my question...

Comment: ...elsewhere. I am aware of the reason that there are guidelines, to better organize the question and make them easier to answer, but this should be a rather simple question. So rather than me taking all this time cleaning up the question post (which I don't think was too bad to start) I suppose I will just continue trying to fix it myself or look somewhere else for help.